# Java URL doesn't seem to connect, but no exception thrown

Tags: java, database, http, url, jtable

I have some code that needs to form a connection to a server, and once that connection is formed the server interprets the string that is sent and updates the names in a database. I.e. I send "http://app.sitename.tv/api/add/aName" and it adds "aName" to the database, or i send 
"http://app.sitename.tv/api/remove/aName" and it removes the name.

When I type these links into a browser and run it it works fine. From my program, though, it doesn't throw any exceptions but does not update the database. I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried turning off my firewall but it makes no difference.

```
if ((Boolean) value)
{
    System.out.println("setValue");
    try 
    {
        String bvURL = "http://app.sitename.tv/api/add/" + data.name.get(row);
        URL myURL = new URL(bvURL);
        URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
        myURLConnection.connect();
        System.out.println(bvURL);
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + e);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {   
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e);
    }
}
else if ((Boolean) value == false)
{
    System.out.println("setValue");
    try 
    {
        String bvURL = "http://app.sitename.tv/api/remove/" + data.name.get(row);
        URL myURL = new URL(bvURL);
        URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
        myURLConnection.connect();
        System.out.println(bvURL);
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + e);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {   
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e);

    }
}
```

Comment: What output do you see?

Comment: How,about (a) checking the response and (b) closing the connection... There are a lot of things that aren't covered in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The `URLConnection` you are getting is actually an [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect%28%29). You have opened the connection but not closed it. To request that the `HttpURLConnection` be closed, you should call its [disconnect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect%28%29) method. It could be that the connection needs to be closed in order to ensure that the server completely receives your request and processes it.

For example, you can replace your first try/catch block with this:

```
HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = null;
try {
    String bvURL = "http://app.sitename.tv/api/add/" + data.name.get(row);
    URL myURL = new URL(bvURL);
    myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
    myURLConnection.connect();
    System.out.println(bvURL);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
    System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + e);
} catch (IOException e) {   
    System.err.println("IOException: " + e);
} finally {
    if (myURLConnection != null) {
        myURLConnection.disconnect();
        myURLConnection = null;
    }
}
```

If this still does not work, you may need to get the `InputStream` from the connection, using `getInputStream()`, and consume all the input data before disconnecting.

Comment: He hasn't opened anything so there is nothing to disconnect. There is nothing in this code that will fix the problem.

Comment: @EJP Um, "nothing"?, I did mention opening the `InputStream` at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Quote what I *actually* wrote, thanks. 'There is nothing *in this code* ...' You know that people are just going to cut and paste and stop reading as soon as they think they have something they can use. Just like you did.

Comment: @EJP I answered *before* you did... Anyway, I will not be continuing this off-topic comment thread (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213714/what-should-i-do-with-accusatory-comments)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't check the response code or get the input or output streams, there is no connection at all. All you've done by calling connect() is create an HttpURLConnection object in your own JVM. Nothing more, and specifically nothing on the network whatsoever.